# what does the following statement mean?(sheaf and presheaf)

Tags: sheaf-theory

The stalk of a sheaf at a point is just its stalk as a presheaf — the same deﬁni-
tion applies — and similarly for the germs of a section of a sheaf.

Answer (score 1):

A sheaf is a presheaf with extra (gluing) conditions. Since any sheaf is also a presheaf, any definition one makes with a presheaf also applies to a sheaf.

Answer (score 1):

The stalk of a presheaf $F$ is defined to be at a point $p$ is 
$$F_p= \lim_\rightarrow F(U)$$ where $U$ ranges over the all the subsets containing $p$ and the direct limit homomorphisms are simply the restriction maps from the presheaf structure. The sentence is saying that when asking about the stalks of a sheaf it has the exact same definition, as all sheaves are presheaves. A germ of a section $s$ its natural image in the direct limit, and again whether we are talking about sheaves or presheaves the same definition holds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand it.